# how can I apply command line function on several files

Tags: awk, grep, cut, tr, gnuwin32

Hello I would like to know how to generate a few files on the command lines. Say I am in a directory and

```
B:\>ls
201209  201210  201211  201212  201301  201302  201303  20130605_files_saved.txt  all_files_demande.txt  all_files_dsi.txt
```

Each directory contain a list of files

```
B:\>ls 201209 | head -n5
adifin1e_2012090107155700.bla
adifin1e_2012090404080200.bla
adifin1e_2012090506070000.bla
adifin1e_2012090607080400.bla
adifin1e_2012090707244900.bla
```

I know what I want to apply on each file

```
B:\>tail -n100 201209\adifin1e_2012090107155700.bla | grep DAT | cut -d, -f 11
"31-Aug-2012 21:41:12.950"
"31-Aug-2012 21:41:12.946"
"31-Aug-2012 21:41:12.950"
"31-Aug-2012 21:41:12.946"
"31-Aug-2012 21:41:12.950"
```

My question is how can I apply the same thing to each file in each directory and save the result as a file named with the same name than the file I am greping with another extension (say .res).
I am using gnuWin32 on windows but basic functions like cut/tr/awk... are available

Comment: Maybe I could show you the code for Windows command prompt, but I can't see the pattern `:(`

Comment: @captcha: would be good, what do you need I have not shown here ? Thanks

Comment: Where is the way from `adifin1e_2012090107155700.bla` to `31-Aug-2012 21:41:12.950` ?

Comment: oh you mean you don't know how to tail or grep or cut with the powershell ... ?

Comment: I know `grep`, but not `tail` or `cut`, but I'm sure this could be simulated by awk/sed.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps

```
find . -type f -name "*.bla" | xargs gawk -F, "/DAT/ {print $11 > FILENAME \".res\"}"
```

I might not have the quoting right for a windows command shellprompt.

Comment: it is running but the files are massinve so I need the `tail` and `cut` part, how can I include this ?

Comment: this would be a lot easier with a proper shell. Does gnuwin32 include bash?

Comment: unfortunately no :(, the only shell I have is the *** windows powershell